# Where to add a separator for mybatis collections(List)

Tags: mybatis

### Mapper.xml

```
<insert id="courseUploads" parameterType="com.technoshinelabs.eduskill.bean.Course" useGeneratedKeys="true" keyColumn="id" keyProperty="id">
    insert into
    course_uploads
    (course_id, training_provider_logo, assignment_material, course_image, trainer_image, created_date, updated_date)
    values(
    #{courseId}, 
    <foreach item="Course" collection="trainingProviderPath" >
        #{Course} 
    </foreach>,
    <foreach item="Course" collection="assignmentMaterialPath">
        #{Course} 
    </foreach>,
    #{courseImagePath},
    <foreach item="Course" collection="trainerImagePath">
        #{Course} 
    </foreach>,
     now(), now() 
    )
</insert>
```

How do I add a separator for the above `list(item="Course")`, this list will have multiple data, each data needs to be separated by some separator, well the data needs to be stored in the database, please do help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `separator` attribute.

e.g.)

```
<foreach item="Course" collection="foo" separator="||">
    #{Course}
</foreach>
```

Specifically, what of SQL do you want to generate?